# Get list of unique records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following table which lists the employees and their corresponding managers:

```
id | employeeid | managerid
1  | 34256      | 12789
2  | 21222      | 34256
3  | 12435      | 34256
.....
.....
```

What is the recommended way to list out all distinct employees(id) in a single list.
Note that all managers may not be listed under the employeeid column (as he may not have a manager in turn).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand this correctly:
This will unite all distict Employee IDs avoiding duplicates from between the two column (`UNION`)

```
SELECT employeeid  AS Employee
FROM tableA
UNION
SELECT managerid AS Employee
FROM tableA
```

Comment: shouldn't it rather be a distinct on the union rather that a union of distincts ? Or will the union eliminate duplicates ? Just asking for my personal information :-)

Comment: Yes, you're right `Union` will remove the duplicates :)

Answer (score 0):

This should d it :

```
SELECT DISTINCT employeeid FROM yourtablename
```

But seriously, by googling the keyword "distinct" you could have found out very easily yourself ! Or did I miss something out ?

Comment: please read the last line of the question-distinct on employeeid will not give me all the employees.

Comment: Well, if you mean that your managers aren't listed as employees and that you need to add to the list of employee id's the list of manager id's, then that means your datamodel is not good. All managers should be employees, allowing the managerid field to be either empty, either a default number indicating they're at the top of the hierarchy

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, employeeid, managerid
FROM
(SELECT yourtablename.*,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY managerid ORDER BY employeeid DESC) AS RN
FROM yourtablename) AS t
WHERE RN = 1
ORDER BY ID
```